# Convert UML to PHP code and vice versa

Tags: php, ide, uml

I use to work using the visual studio IDE where you can use a UML editor to create a class diagram which  can be converted to code (and vice versa) and need to have that ability when working in open source PHP projects.  My question is  there any way to convert UML class diagram into PHP code and vice versa .

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ but be sure to [provide enough information](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it was off-topic. Thanks for your tip

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Visual Paradigm for NetBeans IDE - 
https://netbeans.org/features/uml/

It is a plugin that you can add to the NetBeans IDE. It has "Code generation features for Java, C++, PHP and more".

Comment: Many thanks , can this plugin convert UML class diagram to code ?

Comment: Also is it a UML editor ?

Comment: I have not tried it but from what they are describing in https://netbeans.org/features/uml/ you have a UML editor and you can generate php code based on the UML diagram. Good luck!